# Python JSON schema mining

Tags: json, jsonschema, python-jsonschema

I need some step-by-step tutorial or some papers that I can learn how to create my own JSON schema mining tool. It would be great if someone can share sources or ideas. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "JSON Schema mining"?

Comment: I have JSON data and I want to infer JSON schema for the given JSON data. If you know some known algorithms for JSON schema inference, it would very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Here are a couple implementations of something similar: https://jsonschema.net/#/editor https://github.com/snowplow/schema-guru http://schemaguru.snowplowanalytics.com/.  You could study those.  I got these from http://json-schema.org/implementations.html#schema-generation